# How could this happed: iOS UITablveViewCell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

There is my tableView code and I am using a costom cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *IOsCell = @"IOsCell";  
    IOsCellViewController *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IOsCell];
    if ( cell == nil ) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IOsCellViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

and my costom cell view has a few labels in it:

[image]

The part I'm struggling with is just looks like the picture.

At the bottom
of the UITableView there is a cell view.

[image]

I dont know how could this happed and how to fix this.

I hope I'm clear enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Make sure your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is returning the right number (from your screenshot, it looks like it should return at least 4 for that section)
2. Make sure your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` is returning the correct height for that custom cell

And a classic one I've been burnt with a few times: make sure your delegate is wired correctly so that those methods are infact being called.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath & - (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section these two function make this trouble I think, I set the hight of the last row of the tableView 44, but others' hight are all 150, the last row will call the function that reload more data from the webService.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return height_of_your_cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a UIView in the tableFooterView property. It might be there from interface builder. You can remove it in `-viewDidLoad` of the table view controller by doing

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
```